Testing cpi_events: Is there any way to receive transaction return data using Anchor bankrun?
I want to test cpi_event emission in my anchor bankrun tests. Using normal anchor testing with a local validator I can do this, but once I use bankrun I am unable to fetch any transaction return data.
For example:
context = await startAnchor("", [{name: "my_program", programId: programAddress}], []);
provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
program = new Program<MyProgram>(IDL, provider);

const tx = await program.methods.initialize(treasury.publicKey, default_validator.publicKey).transaction();

const latestBlockhash = await context.banksClient.getLatestBlockhash();
tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash[0];
tx.feePayer = provider.publicKey;
tx.sign(provider.wallet.payer);

const result = await context.banksClient.simulateTransaction(tx, "confirmed");

This returns null for both result.result AND result.meta.returnData. Any ideas on how to capture the return data or test cpi_event emission?
